# Unity Animation Rigging issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem with IK and animation. When I want to edit the animation in Play Mode and click on Preview or record, the skeleton of the model moves out and Rig Builder seems to stop working. With such a problem, it is almost impossible to edit animations.
When I did exactly the same actions in another project, there was no such problem. How can this problem be solved?

Video with problem: **https://youtu.be/99U9qKLfA3U**

I added IK to layers in Animator. I turned off my script, which moved the position of the hands in the game. I tried to edit the animation by adding keyframes. None of this helped.